# Exception thrown at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll)

Tags: qt, paraview

I'm trying to run a Qt based program that I download from here (https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/tree/master/Examples%2FCustomApplications%2FClone1) on Windows 10, but I'm getting this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
```

What I did:

Open `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` and execute: `cmake-gui` with
the path of my app.

Add:

```
Qt5_DIR = C:/Qt/5.9.9/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5
ParaView_DIR =
C:\path\paraview\build\install\lib\cmake\paraview-5.7
```

Then:

```
configure
generate
```

Then in  `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` I cd into
`C:\Users\Escape\Desktop\escape\build>` and execute: `ninja`

I added some path:

```
set PATH=C:\...\paraview\build\install\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=C:\Qt\5.9.9\msvc2015_64\bin;%PATH%
```

Otherwise it wouldn't find the files:

```
pqComponents-pv5.7.dll
pqApplicationComponents-pv5.7.dll
pqCore-pv5.7.dll
vtkGUISupportQt-pv5.7.dll
Qt5Widgetsd.dll
Qt5Guid.dll
Qt5Cored.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
Qt5Network.dll
```

Now, I get no errors but nothing happens when I execute `paraview_clone1` in the terminal. Like, it loads something for a few seconds but then nothing.

If I run it with the Visual Studio 2015 Community I get the error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Exception thrown at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Exception thrown at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Exception thrown at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x000000005207AAD7 (Qt5Core.dll) in paraview_clone1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

The program '[4224] paraview_clone1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I also run `windeployqt paraview_clone1.exe` which created several files but I still get the same result.

```
/iconengines
/imageformats
/platforms
/translations
conccrt140d.dll
d3dcompiler_47.dll
libEGLd.dll
libGLESV2d.dll
msvcp140d.dll
opengl32sw.dll
paraview_clone1.exe
paraview_clone1.ilk
paraview_clone1.pbd
Qt5Cored.dll
Qt5Guid.dll
Qt5Svgd.dll
Qt5Widgetsd.dll
vccorlib140d.dll
vcruntime140d.dll
```

What's it's happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: The example you link is not compatible with ParaView 5.7.0 afaik. it should not even compile.

Comment: What do you mean? It has been working on my mac

Comment: The link you provide is from ParaView master, not 5.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message on windows. In my case it was because I installed MiKTeX which also uses Qt5 dll files, but there was some sort of incompatibility. Luckily all I had to do was to remove MiKTeX path from the windows path environnement and it all worked out great after that.